# bibtex: To have no pagebreak before Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

How can I avoid going to a new page for bibliography if I am using bibtex (not biblatex)?

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\cite{joachims1998making}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}  
\bibliography{scrap_ref}
\end{document}
```

Content of scrap_ref.bib:

```
@techreport{joachims1998making,
title={Making large-scale SVM learning practical},
author={Joachims, Thorsten},
year={1998},
institution={Technical Report, SFB 475: Komplexit{\"a}tsreduktion in 
Multivariaten Datenstrukturen, Universit{\"a}t Dortmund}
}
```

Comment: It depends on your code. Usually, this is determined by your class. Without code for a minimal document demonstrating the issue, it is hard to say. In a default `article`, for example, there is not necessarily a new page, although there might be if there isn't enough room, given the penalties etc. currently active.

Comment: @cfr I am using "report" as my document class.  I edited the question and included an example.  Thanks.

Comment: So you want new pages before all the other chapters, except for the bibliography? That seems rather strange.

Comment: Since you have aresponse below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)). This shows that the answer helped you/ solved your problem, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part [of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

To prevent the newpage, you could temporarily redefine `\clearpage` which is normally issued at the start of a new chapter.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{joachims1998making,
title={Making large-scale SVM learning practical},
author={Joachims, Thorsten},
year={1998},
institution={Technical Report, SFB 475: Komplexit{\"a}tsreduktion in 
Multivariaten Datenstrukturen, Universit{\"a}t Dortmund}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\cite{joachims1998making}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

{
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{} 
\bibliography{\jobname}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works.  How can I keep the bibliography in a separate file?

Comment: @Seeda The same way you did before, I just used the `filecontents` environment for testing. Remove it and change back to `\bibliography{scrap_ref}`